# Compile assembler for Android using NDK

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile some given assembler files (.S) for Android using the NDK. Unfortunately I'm getting the same error for each line: *Error: bad instruction*

Extract of the code:

```
#define FLAG_C 70(%ebx)

lsr_carry:
    cmpb    $32, %cl
    jae lsr_carry_32
    testb   %cl, %cl
    je  lsr_carry_zero
    shrl    %cl, %eax
    setc    FLAG_C
lsr_carry_zero:
    ret
lsr_carry_32:
    jne ls_carry_33
    shll    $1, %eax
    setc    FLAG_C
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
ls_carry_33:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movb    %al, FLAG_C
    ret
```

I think I havent understood the basics of assembler programming. Does anyone can help me?

Comment: 3mx if don't know please don't tell wrong things!
add to Application.mk this line:
APP_ABI := x86
and your code will be builded for x86 platforms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to compile x86 code. Most Android devices run on ARM and the public NDK compiles only for ARM.

Comment: Is it possible to convert it for ARM? Or are there big differences between the two?

Comment: No. They're just completely different architectures, with different opcodes, registers, flags, modes.

Answer (score 2):

It appears like you're trying to plug x86 assembly into Android? Most current Android devices are using the ARM architecture, which is a completely different language with entirely different opcodes.

That aside, I would recommend against using Assembly in the first place (well, unless you have existing code that you're trying to port.)

Comment: Not completely true. Some Google TVs run Android on x86.